# Curve fitting of complex variable in Matlab

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

I want to solve the following system of equations shown in the image below,

The matrix system

[image]

where the component of the matrix A is complex numbers with the angle (theta) runs from `0 to 2*pi` which has m divisions, and `n = 9`. The known value `z = x + iy.` Suppose the x and y of matrix z is

```
z =

     0    1.0148
0.1736    0.9848
0.3420    0.9397
0.5047    0.8742
0.6748    0.8042
0.8419    0.7065
0.9919    0.5727
1.1049    0.4022
1.1757    0.2073
1.1999         0
1.1757   -0.2073
1.1049   -0.4022
0.9919   -0.5727
0.8419   -0.7065
0.6748   -0.8042
0.5047   -0.8742
0.3420   -0.9397
0.1736   -0.9848
     0   -1.0148
```

How do you solve them iteratively? Notice that the value of the first component of the desired constants must equal 1. I am working with Matlab.

Comment: Do you already have a numeric method in mind and need help implementing it? Otehrwise, you should check another site, like https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: thanks @giusti I am using Matlab and am hoping any built-in Matlab function can be used to solve the problem?

Comment: Why iteratively? Gauss–Markov didn't work? Because to me this really looks like standard linear regression.

Comment: @Marco, thanks. I am not familiar with Gauss-Markov but will get some more information about it. There are two things involved in this problem, first is the complex number and, second, is the constraint for the first constants i.e. must equal 1. Any idea how to solve them using the method use mentioned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply [**simple multilinear regression**](http://www.stat.yale.edu/Courses/1997-98/101/linmult.htm) for **complex valued data**.

#### Step 1. Get the matrix ready for linear regression

Your linear system

[image]

written without matrices, becomes

[image]

that rearranged yelds

[image]

If you rewrite it with matrices you get

[image]

#### Step 2. Apply multiple linear regression

Let the system above be

[image]

where

[image]

Now you can apply **linear regression**, that returns the best fit for `α` when

[image]

where

[image]

is the **conjugate transpose**.

---

### In MATLAB

```
Y = Z - A(:,1);             % Calculate Y subtracting the first col of A from Z
R = A(:,:); R(:,1) = [];    % Calculate R as an exact copy of A, just without first column
Rs = ctranspose(R);         % Calculate R-star (conjugate transpose of R)
alpha = (Rs*R)^(-1)*Rs*Y;   % Finally apply multiple linear regression
alpha = cat(1, 1, alpha);   % Add alpha1 back, whose value is 1
```

or, if you prefer **built-ins**, have a look at [`regress`](https://mathworks.com/help/stats/regress.html) function:

```
Y = Z - A(:,1);             % Calculate Y subtracting the first col of A from Z
R = A(:,:); R(:,1) = [];    % Calculate R as an exact copy of A, just without first column
alpha = regress(Y, R);      % Finally apply multiple linear regression
alpha = cat(1, 1, alpha);   % Add alpha1 back, whose value is 1
```

Comment: Hi @Marco, thanks. It produces exactly what I need. However, when I back calculate the value of `z` listed above with `A*alpha`, I could not reproduce `z`. What did I miss here? Shouldn't it be just a standard matrix multiplication between `A` and `alpha`? Recall that the angle (theta) runs from '0 - 2*pi' which has 'm=37' divisions, and `n = 9`.

Comment: @BeeTiau A linear system `Ax = b` has *one and only one* exact solution **if and only if** the matrix `A` is square and invertible, hence to be able to reproduce `z` from your calculated `alpha` you'd need `R` to be square (only if `A` is `m × m+1`) and invertible (depends on the values). Otherwise the system may not have exact solutions, and that's why you use **regression**. Regression gives you the **best** fit, where an **exact** fit doesn't exist. That's why you don't get exactly `z` when you multiply: it's mathematically impossible.

Comment: Furthermore, if the errors on your data have expectation zero and are uncorrelated and have equal variances, the **Gauss–Markov theorem** states that such `alpha` estimated with linear regression is the one that **maximizes the [likelihood function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation)**, hence you couldn't do better than that. (In case the variance is not equal but you know the *covariance* matrix `Σ` the you can estimate `alpha` with: `(R* · Σ^(-1) · R)^(-1) · R* · Σ^(-1) · Y`.)

Comment: thanks again! I have posted another question in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2661604/conformal-mapping-of-complex-function where I tried to obtain the variable to conformally map an irregular shape into a unit circle.